# Save multi-level array using Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have problem to save this data using Laravel-7 model

this is my data

```php
    $supplier = [
      'name'  => 'Supplier 1',
      'pic'   => [
        [
          'name' => 'PIC 1',
          'phone_number'  => [
            ['number' => '111111'],
            ['number' => '123456']
          ]
        ],
        [
          'name' => 'PIC 2',
          'phone_number'  => [
            ['number' => '222222']
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ];
```

And this is my models
`Supplier.php`

```php
    // Supplier.php
    public function supplier_pic()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SupplierPIC');
    }
```

and the other models

```php
    // SupplierPIC.php
    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Supplier');
    }

    public function pic_phone_number()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SupplierPICPhoneNumber');
    }
```

```php
    // SupplierPICPhoneNumber.php
    public function supplier_pic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SupplierPIC');
    }
```

How to save those data on controller ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to break it down into it's constituent objects.

In your case, it is one `Supplier` object with two `SupplierPIC` objects, each of which has a `SupplierPICPhoneNumber`

1. **Create Supplier**

```
$supplier = Supplier::firstOrCreate([
   'name' => 'Supplier 1'
]);
```

2. **Create Supplier PIC(s)**

```
collect($data['pics'])->each(function ($pic) use ($supplier) {
    // Create the PIC
    $x = SupplierPIC::create([
        'name' => $pic['name']
    ]);

    // Attach it to the supplier
    $supplier->supplier_pic()->save($x);

    // Attach phone numbers
    collect($pic['phone_number'])->each(function ($number) use ($x) {
        // Create the PIC Phone number
        $y = SupplierPICPhoneNumber::create([
            'number' => $pic['number']
        ]);
        // Attach the number to the PIC
        $x->pic_phone_number()->save($y);
    });
});
```

---

**Suggestions**

- The naming of your relationships doesn't follow best practice which is a little confusing. Try naming things that are use a `hasMany` type relationship with a plural (i.e. `pic_phone_numbers` rather than `pic_phone_number`)
- Do you need an entire model for `SupplierPICPhoneNumber`? A json column may be better suited.

Comment: Whoaa, thank you, its very helpfull, and thanks for your suggestions